# Correct form for eccentric squats on slant board for treating patellar tendonitis

Tags: recovery, exercise-technique, knees, rehabilitation

In the book by Martin Koban "Beating Patellar Tendonitis" the correct form for eccentric squats on a slant board for treating patellar tendonitis involves having the shins as vertical as possible with little to no forward movement.  However, all of the videos of this exercise I can find on the internet show quite a bit of forward knee motion, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-4tQxO8_QU

In the correct form for eccentric squats on a slant board for patellar tendonitis, should the shin bone remain vertical or does it not really matter?

Comment: Knee position does not only depend on where you want to put them, but also on where you're _able_ to put them without toppling over. This depends on the angle of your slant board and your anatomy (lengths of thighs and shins). So if shins _must_ be vertical (Which I don't know, but I'm sure others will), a differently angled board might help with that. Another factor could be bar position on the back (high bar, low bar) and the angle of your back when squatting.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning behind keeping your shins vertical is this:

> Moving the shin angle to 90 degrees relative to the floor allows the shin bone and the thigh bone to roll atop one another, reducing stress, says physical therapist Dr. Charlie Weingroff. --[LiveStrong.com](http://www.livestrong.com/article/210666-patellar-tendon-rehab-exercises/)

Many people probably do this poorly because they haven't learned to [hip hinge](http://breakingmuscle.com/mobility-recovery/establishing-your-drive-train-screening-and-correcting-the-hip-hinge). I would guess that the more severe your tendonitis, or the more your thigh bone is positioned to create this stress, the more important vertical shins will be. Do your best and use your knee pain as a guide to whether it's good enough.